# Why are matplotlib labels not editable in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, svg

There is a related question [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/91150/edit-text-in-svg-file). I generate a graph using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

WALK_LENGTH = 1_000
random_signs = np.random.choice([-1,1], WALK_LENGTH)
random_signs[0] = 0
random_walk = random_signs.cumsum()
plt.plot(random_walk)
plt.savefig("random_walk.svg")
```

The image looks like this:

[image]

I would like to change the fonts of the tick labels, but cannot. Why is this? The previous answer mentions something about a "text outline", but I don't know what this is. **In the svg file format, what is the "text outline" mentioned in the linked answer, and why does this prevent me from editing text?**

Comment: Not an answer, but I believe that the default for matplotlib is to store .svg text as graphics, not editable text. Perhaps have a look at this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50345077/how-do-i-save-the-text-in-python-plots-editable-in-svg-files) for an idea of how to possibly solve this.